# foreign key construction and population with gorm

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am brand new to go and I decided a todo app would serve as a starter project. I started setting up the db (design decisions aside) I was wondering if there is a cleaner way to implement the foreign keys I am using?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4"
    "gorm.io/driver/mysql"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
    "net/http"
)

type Atom struct {
    ID        uint `gorm:"primaryKey;autoIncrement;"`
    Goal      string
    Solution  string
    Method    string
    OwnerID   int
    OwnerType string
}

type Idea struct {
    gorm.Model
    Atom Atom `gorm:"polymorphic:Owner;"`
    //AtomFK Atom `gorm:"foreignKey:AtomID;references:ID;constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:SET NULL;"`
    AtomID uint
}
type Task struct {
    gorm.Model
    Atom   Atom `gorm:"polymorphic:Owner;"`
    AtomID uint
}
type Todo struct {
    gorm.Model
    Atom   Atom `gorm:"polymorphic:Owner;"`
    AtomID uint
}

func main() {
    dsn := "################################"//don't worry these are correct
    db, err := gorm.Open(mysql.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        panic("failed to connect database")
    }
    db.AutoMigrate(&Atom{})
    db.AutoMigrate(&Idea{})
    db.AutoMigrate(&Task{})
    db.AutoMigrate(&Todo{})

    //db.Clauses(clause.OnConflict{UpdateAll: true}).Create(&Idea{Atom: Atom{Goal: "make blackboard app", Solution: "use go", Method: "write code"}})
    db.Create(&Idea{Atom: Atom{Goal: "make blackboard app", Solution: "use go", Method: "write code"}})
    type lastAtom struct {
        ID        uint `gorm:"primaryKey;autoIncrement;"`
        OwnerID   int
        OwnerType string
    }
    var la lastAtom
    db.Raw("Select id,owner_id,owner_type FROM atoms ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1").Scan(&la)
    var stmt string = fmt.Sprintf("UPDATE %s SET atom_id = %d WHERE id = %d", la.OwnerType, la.ID, la.OwnerID)
    db.Exec(stmt)
```

I just went to straight sql after I looked around the docs for 2-3 hours and couldn't make it work within gorm syntax. Any hints on better syntax would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I come out with a solution for what I got from your question. First, let me share the code, then I'll walk you through all of the relevant parts.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

type Atom struct {
    ID        uint `gorm:"primaryKey;autoIncrement;"`
    Goal      string
    Solution  string
    Method    string
    OwnerID   int
    OwnerType string
}
type Idea struct {
    gorm.Model
    Atom Atom `gorm:"polymorphic:Owner;"`
}
type Task struct {
    gorm.Model
    Atom Atom `gorm:"polymorphic:Owner;"`
}
type Todo struct {
    gorm.Model
    Atom Atom `gorm:"polymorphic:Owner;"`
}

func main() {
    dsn := "host=localhost port=54322 user=postgres password=postgres dbname=postgres sslmode=disable"
    db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    db.AutoMigrate(&Atom{}, &Idea{}, &Task{}, &Todo{})

    db.Create(&Idea{
        Atom: Atom{
            Goal:     "make blackboard app",
            Solution: "use go",
            Method:   "write code",
        },
    })
    db.Create(&Task{
        Atom: Atom{
            Goal:     "second atom",
            Solution: "lorem",
            Method:   "test code",
        },
    })
    db.Create(&Todo{
        Atom: Atom{
            Goal:     "make whiteboard app",
            Solution: "use rust",
            Method:   "debug code",
        },
    })

    // code to get the last atom
    var atom Atom
    if err := db.Model(&Atom{}).Last(&atom).Error; err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(atom)
}
```

We can divide the code into two parts. Let's start with the struct's definition.

##### Struct's definition

Here, I got rid of the field `AtomID` you put within the `Idea`, `Task`, and `Todo` structs. The remaining code is the same as before.

##### The DB logic

First, I inserted some dummy data in the DB by using the GORM capabilities. As this association is an `one2one` you've to specify the `Atom` field every time you're about to insert a related record.
The reading part is even simpler. You care about the last `Atom` inserted based on what I got, GORM provides us with the `Last` method that automatically does what you wrote in the `Raw` method. The update logic isn't clear enough to me but for sure can be achieved with some already built-in methods.

If you need any other help, just let me know, thanks!